# How to create an alert in Swift with a custom image?

Tags: swift

I'd like to add a custom image (one that's dynamically referenced in a CDN) to the iOS alert modal.

How can I do this in Swift?

Comment: "iOS alert modal"? You are talking about the UIAlertController? Have you tried anything yet? What is your current code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using the default `UIAlertView`, or `UIAlertController`. You can create your own `UIViewController` and present it modally using the right presentation style. The is how the `UIAlertController` most likely is implemented too.